# How to make named import be the default behavior when importing from XML?

Tags: android, kotlin, import, xml-namespaces

I have the following imports in my activity -

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_checkout.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_checkout.checkout_activity_products_recyclerview as productsRecyclerView
```

and I was wondering if it is possible to configure in the IDE that when I am calling a name of a view from XML it will automatically name it for me the name I want with the blinking underline waiting for me to type it's name? rather than me doing it manually?

Comment: Are you need to start auto import into the android studio?

Comment: I can't understand you bro

Comment: That would be cool feature, but there are problems with it. What would happen if you rename the id?

Comment: uhm...what would the problem actually be?

Answer (score 1):

Please find below screen shot for start auto import

[image]

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: No sorry this has no effects at all and not what I was looking for. I am looking for an automated named imports like the one I showed in the main post